# Como criar uma div dinamicamente usando dados da base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma pagina de administração denominada (`admin.aspx`) com uma tabela que tem dados que eu vou buscar da minha base de dados do SQL Server. A minha ideia é neste pagina eu selecionar os dados que eu preciso e ao clicar num botão, criar uma div dinamicamente na pagina (`filmes.aspx`) com os dados que eu selecionei na pagina anterior só que nao estou a conseguir fazer. O layout da div que eu tenho em mente é o seguinte:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
      <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h3>Titulo</h3>
    <h4>Ano de Lançamento</h4>
    <p>Sinopse</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="portfolio-item.html">Mais detalhes</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou seja, da pagina (`admin.aspx`) eu quero buscar os valores do titulo, ano de lançamento, sinopse e substituir na div que eu tenho em cima como exemplo. Tudo isto acontecendo dinamicamente, ou seja, os dados ficam na pagina sempre não desaparecendo quando eu termino o programa e também pretendo continuar a adicionar divs sem substituir os dados da criada anteriormente.

Comment: Está usando o ADO.net, o Entity, o NHibernate? O que está usando para banco de dados?